# fabric8: Add a configmap

Tags: maven, fabric8

I've been able to build and deploy my spring boot service image into openshift using fabric8 plugin.

I need to add some configmap.

I've tried to add an striaghtforward `configmap.yml` into `src/main/fabric8`.

Currently, I'm getting this message:

```
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:4.4.1:resource (default-cli) @ connector ---
[INFO] F8: Using Container image name of namespace: arxius-linia
[INFO] F8: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] F8: spring-boot: Using Container image fabric8/java-centos-openjdk11-jdk:1.6.3 as base / builder
[INFO] F8: using resource templates from /home/jeusdi/projects/arxius-linia/connector/src/main/fabric8
[INFO] F8: fmp-controller: Adding a default Deployment
[INFO] F8: fmp-service: Adding a default service 'connector' with ports [8080]
[WARNING] F8: fmp-git: Could not detect any git remote
[WARNING] F8: fmp-git: Could not detect any git remote
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.839 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-25T14:08:29+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:4.4.1:resource (default-cli) on project connector: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:4.4.1:resource failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

My `configmap.yml` is:

```yml
data:
  application.properties: |
    spring.profiles.active=dev
```

My current related `pom.xml` configuration is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

It's zero configuration based.

Any ideas about how to add my `configmap.yml`?

Comment: Hi, Fabric8 Maven Plugin is now migrated to Eclipse JKube https://github.com/eclipse/jkube . Could you please see if switching to [`kubernetes-maven-plugin`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jkube/kubernetes-maven-plugin/1.0.2/maven-plugin) or [`openshift-maven-plugin`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.jkube%20AND%20a:openshift-maven-plugin%20AND%20v:1.0.2) resolves your issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I just noticed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Fabric8/Eclipse JKube team.

As I've mentioned in the comment, you should try switching to [Eclipse JKube](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube) since it's going to be supported in future. [Migrating to Eclipse JKube](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/09/21/migrating-from-fabric8-maven-plugin-to-eclipse-jkube-1-0-0/) is as simple as running this goal:

```sh
$ mvn org.eclipse.jkube:kubernetes-maven-plugin:migrate
```

I tried out your `ConfigMap` resource fragment with this version of `kubernetes-maven-plugin` in one of [my demo projects](https://github.com/r0haaaan/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments):

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
        <artifactId>kubernetes-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>resource</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I added your `ConfigMap` to my `src/main/jkube` directory:

```sh
eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments : $ cat src/main/jkube/second-configmap.yaml 
data:
  application.properties: |
    spring.profiles.active=dev
```

When I did `mvn k8s:resource k8s:apply`, I was able to see `ConfigMap` being created:

```sh
eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments : $ mvn k8s:resource k8s:apply
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------< org.eclipse.jkube.quickstarts.maven:external-resources >-------
[INFO] Building Eclipse JKube :: Quickstarts :: Maven :: External Resources 1.1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.0:resource (default-cli) @ external-resources ---
[INFO] k8s: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] k8s: spring-boot: Using Docker image quay.io/jkube/jkube-java-binary-s2i:0.0.9 as base / builder
[INFO] k8s: Using resource templates from /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/src/main/jkube                                                                                                 
[INFO] k8s: jkube-controller: Adding a default Deployment
[INFO] k8s: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds                                                                                  
[INFO] k8s: jkube-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds                                                                                  
[INFO] k8s: jkube-service-discovery: Using first mentioned service port '80' 
[INFO] k8s: jkube-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/ribbon-serviceaccount.yml resource                                                       
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/external-resources-service.yml resource                                                  
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/game-config-env-file-configmap.yml resource                                              
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/second-configmap.yml resource                                                            
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/external-resources-deployment.yml resource
[INFO] k8s: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes/my-ingress-ingress.yml resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.0:apply (default-cli) @ external-resources ---
[INFO] k8s: Using Kubernetes at https://192.168.39.102:8443/ in namespace default with manifest /home/rohaan/work/repos/eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments/target/classes/META-INF/jkube/kubernetes.yml 
[INFO] k8s: Creating a ServiceAccount from kubernetes.yml namespace default name ribbon
[INFO] k8s: Created ServiceAccount: target/jkube/applyJson/default/serviceaccount-ribbon-1.json
[INFO] k8s: Creating a Service from kubernetes.yml namespace default name external-resources
[INFO] k8s: Created Service: target/jkube/applyJson/default/service-external-resources-1.json
[INFO] k8s: Creating a ConfigMap from kubernetes.yml namespace default name game-config-env-file
[INFO] k8s: Created ConfigMap: target/jkube/applyJson/default/configmap-game-config-env-file-1.json
[INFO] k8s: Creating a ConfigMap from kubernetes.yml namespace default name second
[INFO] k8s: Created ConfigMap: target/jkube/applyJson/default/configmap-second-1.json
[INFO] k8s: Creating a Deployment from kubernetes.yml namespace default name external-resources
[INFO] k8s: Created Deployment: target/jkube/applyJson/default/deployment-external-resources-1.json
[INFO] k8s: Applying Ingress my-ingress from kubernetes.yml
[INFO] k8s: HINT: Use the command `kubectl get pods -w` to watch your pods start up
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.821 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-09T12:37:38+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I checked, I was able to see `ConfigMap` created in `default` namespace:

```sh
eclipse-jkube-sample-with-resource-fragments : $ kubectl get configmap second -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application.properties: |
    spring.profiles.active=dev
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-09T07:07:37Z"
...
```